# Workbox/Vue: Create a custom variation on an existing caching strategy handler

Tags: vue.js, caching, vuejs2, progressive-web-apps, workbox

*Background:*

I'm building an SPA (Single Page Application) PWA (Progressive Web App) using Vue.js. I've a remote PostgreSQL database, serving the tables over HTTP with PostgREST. I've a working Workbox Service Worker and IndexedDB, which hold a local copy of the database tables. I've also registered some routes in my service-worker.js; everything is fine this far....

I'm letting Workbox cache GET calls that return tables from the REST service. For example:
https://www.example.com/api/customers will return a json object of the customers.

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute('https://www.example.com/api/customers', workbox.strategies.staleWhileRevalidate())
```

At this point, I need Workbox to do the stale-while-revalidate pattern, **but** to:

1. Not use a cache, but instead return the local version of this table, which I have stored in IndexedDB. (the cache part)
2. Make the REST call, and update the local version, if it has changed. (the network part)

I'm almost certain that there is no configurable option for this in this workbox strategy. So I would write the code for this, which should be fairly simple. The retrieval of the cache is simply to return the contents of the requested table from IndexedDB. For the update part, I'm thinking to add a data revision number to compare against. And thus decide if I need to update the local database.

Anyway, we're now zooming in on the actual question:

*Question:*

Is this actually a good way to use Workbox Routes/Caching, or am I now misusing the technology because I use IndexedDB as the cache?

and

How can I make my own version of the `StaleWhileRevalidate` strategy? I would be happy to understand how to simply make a copy of the existing Workbox version and be able to import it and use it in my Vue.js Service Worker. From there I can make my own necessary code changes.

To make this question a bit easier to answer, these are the underlying subquestions:

- First of all, the `StaleWhileRevalidate.ts` (see link below) is a .ts (TypeScript?) file. Can (should) I simply import this as a module? I propably can. but then I get errors:
- When I to import my custom CustomStaleWhileRevalidate.ts in my main.js, I get errors on all of the current import statements because (of course) the `workbox-core/_private/` directory doesn't exist.

How to approach this?

This is the current implementation on Github:
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/blob/master/packages/workbox-strategies/src/StaleWhileRevalidate.ts

Answer (score 0):

I don't think using the built-in `StaleWhileRevalidate` strategy is the right approach here. It *might* be possible to do what you're describing using `StaleWhileRevalidate` along with a number of [custom plugin callbacks](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/using-plugins#custom_plugins) to override the default behavior... but honestly, you'd end up changing so much via plugins that starting from scratch would make more sense.

What I'd recommend that you do instead is to write a custom [`handlerCallback`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/reference-docs/latest/module-workbox-routing#~handlerCallback) function that implements exactly the logic you want, and returns a `Response`.

```
// Your full logic goes here.
async function myCustomHandler({event, request}) {
  event.waitUntil((() => {
    const idbStuff = ...;
    const networkResponse = await fetch(...);
    // Some IDB operation go here.
    return finalResponse;
  })());
}

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  'https://www.example.com/api/customers',
  myCustomHandler
);
```

You could do this without Workbox as well, but if you're using Workbox to handle some of your unrelated caching needs, it's probably easiest to also register this logic via a Workbox route.